# Eclipse AVD :- I cant create an Android 4.3 virtual emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

Eclipse AVD :- I cant create an Android 4.3 virtual emulator

I have installed all the required SDKs

and when I try to create Android 4.3 emulator with the below configuration, it doent work. I simply get a blank screen. Can anyone please help me out. If I try to edit the Avd device, it shows a message that "no device is selected."

```
device:- Nexus 7 (7.02", 1200 x 1920: xhdpi)
target:- Android 4.3
CPU: ARM

Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2
All the required sdks are isntalled
```

Comment: make sure ARM EABI and Intel X86 Atom System Images are installed in your SDK manger or update SDK manager if any available

Comment: they are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you got Intel i3, i5, i7 processor on your PC try setup Android HAXM emulator.

Comment: I am using OSX 10.9 , do I need to setup HAXM emulator?

Comment: try this link [link](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me from time to time. Check the amount of memory you are giving to that emulator, as  using Windows can be problematic if it is more than 768 Mb. Changing this value sometimes do the trick, but sometimes I'm forced to erase the whole emulator, and make a new one with a fine memory value lower than 768 Mb.

Comment: I am using osx and I am creating an emulator with 512mb of memory. but still its not helping

Comment: I'm sorry to not be able to help you, then. That's all experience I had with that issue. Good luck.